# Server 2016 Tombstone Lifetime

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2016

Does anybody know what the default tombstone lifetime for Server 2016 is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be "180", look here: http://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/rc1210960/sln283178/windows-server-understanding-and-modifying-the-active-directory-tombstone-lifetime?lang=en

Comment: Seems like you're right buddy

Comment: From the @boboes' link: _In the Attribute Editor tab of the properties window, locate the `tombstoneLifetime` attribute. The value of this attribute represents the forest's current tombstone lifetime in days. If the attribute's value shows_ **<not set>**, _the tombstone lifetime of the forest is **60 days**._

Answer (score 2):

You can check your forest's value by launching the ADSI edit tool (ADSIEDIT.msc) and browsing the Configuration partition for the AD forest. Navigate to CN=Directory Service, CN=Windows NT, CN=Services, CN=Configuration, DC=domain, DC=com. Right-click the CN=Directory Service object and select Properties. Look for the tombstoneLifetime value. 2016 Server is 180 Days. Hope this helps!